# Laravel @foreach makes my site not responsive

Tags: php, laravel, responsive-design, laravel-blade

I ma using Laravel for a project and the @foreach makes me confuse. 
When i use the next piece of code my desktop page goes crazy and I dont know why:

[image: image here]

But when i type it manually it is responsive. Any suggestions? 
This is the manual way:

[image: image here]

Comment: Don't add code as images.

Comment: Please add your code here as text, not as links to images. It will allow us to see your code easier.

Comment: Also, how does it make your page go crazy/unresponsive? Are there any messages in the log files in `/storage/logs`?

Comment: What about it does not work? Please [edit] your post to add the code directly to your question, so it can be formatting properly for readability.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments or in images as pointed by others, edit your original question and put the code there. Or this question will be closed soon.

Comment: Probably just an issue with using bootstrap here

Comment: Please can you show the value of `$states`?

Answer (score 1):

The above code is perfect only.

May be the issue with using bootstrap here.

**OR**

Try this command :

**php artisan view:clear**